# Exclude whole group when a 'NULL' is present

Tags: sql, group-by, null

I have a table that looks like this:

```
OrderNo | Operation | PlannedStart |PlannedEnd | ActualStart | ActualEnd | OpComplete
   1    |      1    |   01/02/13   |  01/03/13 |    01/03/13 |  01/03/13 |    True
   1    |      2    |   01/03/13   |  01/04/13 |    01/04/13 |  01/05/13 |    True
   2    |      1    |   01/01/13   |  01/02/13 |    01/01/13 |  01/02/13 |    True
   2    |      2    |   01/02/13   |  01/03/13 |    01/02/13 |  01/03/13 |    True
   3    |      1    |   01/01/13   |  01/02/13 |    01/01/13 |  01/02/13 |    True
   3    |      2    |   01/02/13   |  01/03/13 |    01/02/13 |    NULL   |    False
```

and a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT   
    OrderNo, 
    MIN(PlannedStart) AS PlannedStart, 
    MAX(PlannedEnd) AS PlannedEnd,    
    MIN(ActualStart) AS ActualStart, 
    MAX(ActualEnd) AS ActualEnd, 
    DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(PlannedStart), MAX(PlannedEnd)) AS PlannedThroughput, 
    DATEDIFF(hour, MIN(ActualStart), MAX(ActualEnd)) AS ActualThroughput 
FROM Operations 
GROUP BY OrderNo 
ORDER BY ActualThroughput Desc
```

I am trying to find out the actual time taken to complete an order (summing the total time of all of its operations) and later be able to compare it with the planned time.

The code takes the start date of the first operation and the end date of the last operation, it calculates the difference and gives it to me as a number of hours.

The problem arises when an operation in an order has not been completed, it then shows 'NULL' as an actual end. Null is not a value which I can use with the MAX() function to calculate the ActualThroughput(See Code), therefore it takes the last value which is not 'NULL' and gives me an inaccurate result.

I would like to be able to exclude completely all orders (groups) which have not yet been completed. How can I do this?

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab4e4/3

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the NULL values from your SELECT statement using the WHERE clause

```
WHERE NOT ActualEnd IS NULL
```

Comment: If I do this I get no results at all.. canät figure out why

Comment: ok now I figured.. I wrote it like this:

Where ActualEnd is not Null

However this doesnt work, This does not exclude the whole order (group). It only excludes the single rows which have NULL as ActualEnd.

Comment: Ok, so you want to exclude the entire group once there is an NULL value in ActualEnd?  Try this: WHERE OrderNo NOT IN (SELECT OrderNo FROM Operations WHERE ActualEnd IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to remove the whole group immediately points to using HAVING. Then you *just* need to pick an aggregate function that lets you distinguish groups with nulls from those without. There aren't many to look through and most of them deal with nulls in a way that makes them pretty much invisible which isn't useful except for in the case of count. Count not including nulls means you can use it by comparing a known non null column to the one(s) you are worried about. In this case:

```
Having  COUNT(OrderNo) = COUNT(ActualEnd)
```

The sub-query to check for existence also works but depending on the query and tables can get slow and messy fast.